# Disable Intellisense in XAML Editor in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xaml, ide, editor, intellisense

Is there a way to disable Intellisense in the XAML editor in Visual Studio 2008? It is often a big performance drain while typing, and sometimes I'll sit for ten or more seconds waiting while the list automatically popups up.

It appears that in Options->Text Editors->XAML, the Intellisense section is section is unavailable (grayed out). We open documents in Full XAML View, and don't use any third party enhancements.

It's so bad that sometimes I'll just open the file elsewhere and edit what I need, but I'd really like to get this solved so I *don't* have to use an external application.

Comment: I'd hate to be without my intellisense :)

Comment: Sometimes, it's just not worth the drain...I hope VS 2k8 SP2 improves performance, but I'm just not satisfied with it now.

Comment: try deleting intellisense .ncb database..may be it can help?VS will recreate those files on startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my own answer:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Text Editor\XAML\Auto List Members
```

Setting to 0x00000000 solves it.

The "Auto List Params" Key seems to have no effect. To top it off, you can still use <Ctrl+Space> to open it up on demand (for setting an attribute you can't think of the name of, etc.)

Pretty nifty!

Comment: The original value of "Auto List Members" on my machine (VS2010) was 0x00000001 - in case anyone is looking to reverse the change.