# How to disable intellisense for XAML in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, intellisense

yes I know it's unusual, but I actually want to turn of intellisense for XAML editing. If I need it, I can always hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.
I disabled it for all languages via Tools > Options > Text Editor > All languages > General > Statement completion, but it still works for XAML.

Can anybody tell me how I can disable it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to set the following registry key to `0`:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Text Editor\XAML\Auto List Members
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Apparently this is almost the same answer as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162025/disable-intellisense-in-xaml-editor-in-vs2008

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching the default editor for XAML files.

Right click XAML file in solution explorer, then `Open With...`, select `XML editor` and `use as default`.

Bonus feature is that resharper will still work.